# Problem with get methods not having required arguments

Tags: class, methods

```
public class Card
{


private int rank;
private int suit;
public Card(int r,int s){
   
   rank=r;
   suit=s;
   
}
public Card getRank(Card r)
{
    return r;
    
}
public Card getSuit(Card s)
{
    
    return  s;
}
}

private static String toImage(Card card)
{
    return "" + card.getRank() + "cdhs".charAt(card.getSuit()) + ".gif";
}
}
```

The first code is the Card class where I am trying to make getter methods that return rank and suit. The second code is a class that needs to use the get methods but it says "method getSuit/getRank cannot be applied to given types. Required: Card Found :no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to pass the required arguments (a Card object) in the code that you didn't provide but is getting the error.  Either that or take the argument off the method.  What's the problem?  Also, what programming language is this?

Comment: I did provide the code that is getting the error and I am returning Card r/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful to consider that instance methods are intended to work with an instance of the class on which the are defined.  If this is not intuitive, it can be helpful to use the keyword `this` to emphasize this fact until you get used to it.

For example, your method

```
public Card getRank(Card r)
{
    return r;

}
```

makes little sense in an object-oriented environment.  What you are intending to do is retrieve the rank from the Card instance, so there isn't any reason to pass another `Card` instance as an argument.  The use of `this` emphasizes the correct way to write this method:

```
public class Card
{
    private final int rank;
    private final int suit;

    public Card(int r,int s)
    {
        this.rank=r;
        this.suit=s;
    }

    public int getRank()
    {
        return this.rank;
    }
    :
    :
}
```

Comment: I edited it but it says r is not a variable.

Comment: You had made some syntax errors in your method.  I've worked through them, and it should be correct now.

Comment: It says int cannot be converted to Card for return this.rank

Comment: Your instance fields are `int`s, so your method cannot return a `Card` if it intends to return the `rank` field.  I've changed the method return type.

Comment: I keep getting the same error for the second code saying "method getSuit/getRank cannot be applied to given types. Required: Card Found :no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: Yes, you'll need to edit your code so that the changes made to `getRank()` are also applied to `getSuit()`.